# How to prove that the set of all bijections is a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions

I need to prove the following: Let $X$ be a set and $S_X$ the set of all bijections $f: X$ to $X$.  Is $S_X$ a group under composition of functions?

I know that to prove something is a group I need to prove
 $1)$ associativity,
 $2)$ the existence of the identity,
 $3)$ the existence of the inverse.  I have already proved that the composition of functions is associative in a previous problem, though those functions were not bijective.  I'm really stuck on the other two parts.

Comment: Are you comfortable with what the set of all bijections $X \to X$ is? For example, could you write them all down if the set is, say, $X = \{1,2,3\}$?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't seem to be my issue.  I've never been perfect with that concept, but I think understand the basic meaning of bijections.

Comment: The "set of all bijections that maps a function from $X$ to $X$" --- that doesn't make sense. Do you mean "the set of all bijections from $X$ to $X$"? Clearing up linguistic misconceptions like this is a good first step for problems like this.

Comment: @JohnHughes I just edited it to be the problem to the best of my math typing ability.

Comment: Start with the easy ones.  That's somewhat subjective, but most people will find that naming a bijection that works as identity is not hard.

Comment: OK. That's better. Now go ahead and as @Fabio suggests, propose a bijection that might serve as the identity element for "composition".

Comment: In previous problems using composition of functions, the identity has commonly been $x$.  That's my gut reaction for this problem, as any of function composed with this one would result in said function.

Comment: Yes, you'd say that $f(x)=x$ is the identity.  Now, are bijections invertible?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Well shoot, chalk this up to working on little to no sleep while massively overcomplicating the problem.  Thanks

Comment: This is none other than the *symmetric group*.  The bijections are also called *permutations*.

Answer (score 0):

We can define a bijection on $X$ as a map $f\colon X\to X$ with the following:

**Property**: for every $x'\in X$, there is one and only one $x\in X$ such that $x'=f(x)$.

The statement "...*for every $x'\in X$, there is one and only one $x\in X$*..." actually defines a ***map*** $g\colon X\to X$, $x'\mapsto g(x')=x$. Therefore, for every $x\in X$, we get: $x=g(x')=$ $g(f(x))=$ $(gf)(x)$, namely $gf=Id_X$: the map $g$ is said *a left inverse of $f$*. But also, for every $x'\in X$, we get: $x'=f(x)=$ $f(g(x'))=$ $(fg)(x')$, whence also $fg=Id_X$: a left inverse is also a right inverse. Moreover, if $g'$ is another right inverse of $f$, then for every $x\in X$: $f(g'(x))=f(g(x))$, whence (because $f$ is a bijection, see the Property above) $g'(x)=g(x)$, namely $g'=g$. Therefore, for any given bijection $f$, there is a unique (left/right) inverse. Since it depends on $f$ only, the symbol "$f^{-1}$" is a suitable one for it (but "$\tilde f$", "$\hat f$", "$\bar f$", etc. would fit either).

**Lemma 1**. If $f$ is a bijection,  then the inverse $f^{-1}$ is a bijection.

*Proof*. The unique $x$ in the Property is $f(x')$. $\space\Box$

**Lemma 2**. If $f,g$ are bijections,  then the composition $fg$ is a bijection.

*Proof*. The unique $x$ in the Property is $(g^{-1}f^{-1})(x')$. $\space\Box$

By the Lemma 2, $S_X$ is closed under map composition. By the Lemma 1, $S_X$ is also "closed by inverses". The identity map of $X$ (a bijection!) has the property that, for every $f\in X^X$: $fId_X=Id_Xf=f$, and this holds *a fortiori* for every $f\in S_X$. Likewise, the associativity of map composition needs only that the three maps lie in $X^X$, and hence it holds *a fortiori* in $S_X$.